Cauchy's formula and proof verification

Conway defines a rectifiable curve as a path with bounded variation.

So we are asked to prove that the function $\phi$ is continuous. We use that prove that g(z) is entire and hence prove the theorem.
In $z\neq w$ the function $\phi$ is the difference quotient and is obviously continuous as the set is open and $z \neq w$.
For the diagonal $z=z$:
Using the limits $\lim_{w,z\to w,w}\phi(z,w)=f'(w)$ and $\lim_{w,w\to z_0,z_0} (\phi(w,w)=f'(w))=f(z_0)$ and the triangle inequality we can get:
$\lim_{w,z\to z_0,z_0}\phi(z,w)=f'(z_0)$ but only if we approach $(z_0, z_0)$ from $z \neq w$.
We get those two limits from the fact that $\phi$ is the difference quotient for $z\neq w$ and the continuity of the derivative of f. (Conway defines analyticity as having a continuous derivative)
So approaching the point $(z_0,z_0)$ on the diagonal from $z\neq w$ we get the same limit as if we approached $(z_0,z_0)$ from $z=z$, (again cause $f'$ is continuous when we approach the diagonal from the diagonal $\phi$ is continuous) so the limit $\lim_{w,z\to z_0,z_0}\phi(z,w)=f'(z_0)$ exists.
So the function $\phi$ is continuous. To prove that it is analytic in z for each w, I think we can use L'Hospital twice but I am not sure it is valid for this case.
Is this true? I feel I messed up somewhere.
Also here is where I am stuck: using the compactness of the curve and in a neighborhood of z(so we can assume compactness cause the product of two compact spaces is compact) we have the continuity of $\phi$ implies the uniform continuity of $\phi$ that can be used to imply that g(z) is continuous. This is because g is defined using an integral so we need an inequality for $|\phi(z,w) - \phi(y,w)| < \epsilon$ that is valid for all w in the curve, and in a neighbor of y, to pass the inequality through the integral and thus to prove continuity.
But how can I prove g is analytic for $z\in G$?; consider the fact that z can belong to the curve as well cause we need the function g to be entire for the proof.

Btw the text has not proved yet that holomorphic functions are analytic(continuously differentiable)
